# "Hamiltonian operator has no effect on the spin function" what does it mean?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spin

I have read the Levine Quantum Chemistry book and it says "Hamiltonian operator has no effect on the spin function" in chapter 10 (Electron Spin and the Spin-Statistics Theorem)  and does the Hamiltonian operation like the following. Why the g(ms) state is taken out of the Hamiltonian?? Why is it constant with respect to the Hamiltonian?

$$\hat H[\psi(x,y,z)g(m_s)] = g(m_s)\hat H\psi(x,y,z) = E[\psi(x,y,z)g(m_s)]$$

Answer (score 5):

Because the operator $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ only acts on $x$ and not on $y$, we can write

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[f(x)g(y)] = g(y) \left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right]$$

Likewise, in this context, the Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$ only acts on $(x,y,z)$ and not $m_s$. This is explained by Levine<sup>1</sup> in the paragraph immediately preceding this

> To a very good approximation, the Hamiltonian operator for a system of electrons does not involve the spin variables but is a function only of spatial coordinates and derivatives with respect to spatial coordinates [...]

Is there something about this paragraph which you don't understand? This is pretty much all there is to be said on the topic.

---

1. Levine, I. N. *Quantum Chemistry* (7th ed.), p 268

Comment: the spin of an electron is due to the rotational motion about its own axis. Why it should not be there for the Hamiltonian operator?? I mean the electron should also have a rotational kinetic energy due to its motion about its own axis.

Comment: Spin **doesn't** correspond to a physical rotation of the electron! See, e.g. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58020/do-electrons-really-spin If you consider both up spin and down spin to be degenerate, there will not be any term depending on $m_s$ that enters the Hamiltonian (depending on where you set your zero of energy, there might be a *constant* term, but this term doesn't depend on $m_s$).

Comment: To clarify, this is not _the_ Hamiltonian, it is _a_ Hamiltonian, specifically the one that acts on a non-relativistic stationary wavefunction (the time-independent Schrödinger equation, particle in a box/on a ring models, ...). Spin appears naturally in other Hamiltonians, such as Dirac's equation and its many reductions, and is "bolted on" for magnetic perturbations in the Schrödinger equation.